# Django - display method result without url

Tags: django

I am newbie in django and try to build a simple shop system. in my store all customers must charge their accounts with which they can buy a product (credit system).

now i want to display user credit in top of site header in all of the site. i also want to write some functions and display its result in template without special URL.

how can do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You haven't provided any code at all. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also I recommend completing [polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) if you haven't completed it already.

Comment: @gitblame I asked a general question. How to display the result of a method without the use of url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, I think you should use a general template which will be extended for every other page you want to display.

You can achieve that using Jinja template engine adding:

```
{% extends 'general.html' %}
```

in every template you want to display credits

For example:

general.html

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>General</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    <p>{{ user.credit }}</p>

    {% block body %}
    <h1>General</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

another-template.html:

```
{% extends 'general.html' %}

<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>Another template</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    {% block body %}
    <h1>Another template</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Second template will overwrite "block head" and "block body" content, but still display credit from general.html.

Comment: tanks. i found it